# How to navigate react-bootstrap pagination to next page?

Tags: reactjs, pagination, react-bootstrap

I tried to create pagination for my page using react-bootstrap. I want to show the different product when user click the different pagination button But it didn't work, when I click any of the button the product will not be shown. How can I do this ?

**For Example: Page 1 Show item 1-10, Page 2 show item 11-20**

Here's my code:

```
import axios from 'axios';
import Paginations from './Paginations';
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import '../CSS/ProductList.css'

const ProductList = () => {
  const { categoryslug } = useParams()
  const [productList, setProductList] = useState();
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
  const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(1);
  const [itemPerPage] = useState(2);

  useEffect(() =>{
    axios.get(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/data/products/?format=json`).then(res => {
        const products = Object.values(res.data);
        var filteredCategory = products[3].filter((product) => product.category.slug === categoryslug)
        setProductList(filteredCategory)
        setIsLoading(false);
      })
  }, []);

  const indexOfLastPost = currentPage * itemPerPage;
  const indexOfFirstPost = indexOfLastPost - itemPerPage;

  // Change page
  const paginate = pageNumbers => {
    setCurrentPage(pageNumbers);
    console.log(pageNumbers)
  }
  
  if (isLoading) {
    return <h2>Loading...</h2>;
  }

  return (
    <>
      <Row>
        <Paginations
          itemPerPage= {itemPerPage}
          totalItems= {Object.keys(productList).length}
          paginate={paginate}
        />
      </Row>
    </>
  )
}

export default ProductList
```

my pagination component code:

```
import React from 'react'
import { Pagination } from 'react-bootstrap';

function Paginations({itemPerPage, totalItems, paginate}) {
    const pageNumbers =[];
    for (let i = 1; i <= Math.ceil(totalItems/ itemPerPage); i++ ){
      pageNumbers.push(
        <Pagination.Item key={i}  onClick={(i) => paginate(i)}>
          {i}
        </Pagination.Item>
      );
    }

  return (
    <>
      <Pagination className="d-flex justify-content-center mt-5 itemPagination">{pageNumbers}</Pagination>
    </>
  )
}

export default Paginations
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two possible scenarios with pagination: client and backend pagination. With the client pagination you fetch all of the data and then split it into pages according to the amount of elements you want to show per page. For the backend pagination you either request next page every time or you can request certain page directly. Either way you don't get all of the data.

As far as I can see you request all of the data, so you need to split the data into pages and only show a certain page in your UI (table? cards?). On navigate (click on page) you have to do two things then: set pagination page right and show in your UI the right data.

I have created a sandbox with mock data. I don't know which UI you use to show the data, so I created a table with 100 random rows and a pagination with 5 pages. Usually you will also use the pagination arrows (First, Next, Prev, Last), but the logic differs depending on preferences:

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-bootstrap-client-pagination-kp5drs?file=/src/Table.jsx

```
  const handleClick = (page) => {
    setCurrentPage(page);
    const pageIndex = page - 1;
    const firstIndex = pageIndex * rowsPerPage;
    const lastIndex = pageIndex * rowsPerPage + rowsPerPage;
    showData(data.slice(firstIndex, lastIndex));
  };
```